# What is the growth of the rank of a power of a finite simple group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, classification

Which asymptotic bounds (upper and lower) are known for $s_n$ - the minimal number of generators of $S^n$ where $S$ is a nonabelian finite simple group?

Comment: You should probably check the work of J. Wiegold

Comment: @GeoffRobinson which one? do you have a reference?

Comment: He wrote a few papers on "Growth sequences of Groups"

Comment: it's logarithmic, check Thevenaz's elementary argument: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9703201

Comment: I would guess that the average number of independent uniformly random elements you need to pick to generate the group also grows logarithmically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powers of finite simple groups](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/187736/powers-of-finite-simple-groups)

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of this question:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/187736/powers-of-finite-simple-groups

Comment: @IanAgol although you're essentially right I won't vote to close as a duplicate because the question is asked in a much more clear and natural way here than in the linked post

Comment: @Ian Agol: The other question was asking for computations not for asymptotics, in any case this question was not answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One has
$$1 \leq s_n - \frac{\log(n)}{\log|S|} \leq 2r$$
based on an elementary argument in Remark 1.1 in [Moshe Jarden and Alexander Lubotzky, *Random normal subgroups of free pro-finite groups*, J. Group Theory 2 (1999) 213-224], where $r$ denotes the minimal number of generators of $S$. By the classification of finite simple groups, we know that $r = 2$.

Comment: One may find this article here: http://www.tau.ac.il/~jarden/Articles/paper68.pdf