# Number of generators of a group

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

Given a (finite) group $G$. Is there any bounds on the minimum number of generators $d(G)$?

For example, it is clear that $d(G) \geqslant d(G^{ab})$. Where the right hand side can be easily computed. Unfortunately, this does not give much information, e.g. $A_n^{ab}$ is trivial, but $A_n$ has two generators itself.

UPD: Actually, I am more interested in lower bounds.

Comment: The question is quite too general as now stated. Some particular but interesting cases are treated [in this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187736/powers-of-finite-simple-groups) about powers of finite simple groups.

Comment: See http://www.numdam.org/article/RSMUP_1990__83__201_0.pdf

Comment: @YCor partial answers are acceptable too.

Comment: @SemyonAbramyan I hope so :) the point is that for a too broad/open-ended question, too many answers are acceptable. Since there has already been more focussed questions on the subject, you might have a more focussed one, at least taking into account existing ones.

Comment: Lots of bounds have been proved for various specific types of finite groups, such as transitive/primitive subgroups of $S_n$, completely reducible/reducible/primitive subgroups of ${\rm GL}(n,K)$.

Comment: The title of @BenjaminSteinberg's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410612/number-of-generators-of-a-group#comment1053544_410612):  [Lucchini - Some questions on the number of generators of a finite group](http://www.numdam.org/item/RSMUP_1990__83__201_0).

Comment: BTW, what you are calling $n(G)$ is far more commonly denoted by $d(G)$ (I'm not sure why).

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you! I have changed the notation.

Comment: $d(G)\le\lfloor\log_2|G|\rfloor$. More precisely, $d(G)\le\Omega(|G|)$ (i.e., the number of prime divisors of $|G|$, with multiplicity).

Comment: Example of lower bound: If a group has rank $\le k$ then every subgroup of index $m$ has rank $\le 1+m(k-1)$. Application: let $F$ be a finite group and $V$ a finite $F$-module, whose underlying abelian group has rank $m$. Then $F\ltimes V^n$ has rank $\ge 1+(nm-1)/|F|$ (while if $F$ is perfect and $V$ has trivial $F$-coinvariants, $F\ltimes V^n$ is a perfect group). Example: for prime power $q\ge 4$, the perfect group $\mathrm{SL}_2(q)\ltimes (q^2)^n$ has rank $\ge 1+(2n-1)/(q^3-q)$.

Comment: There is a link between $d(G)$ and the subgroup lattice of $G$, see Corollary 7.3 in [this paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3856145).